# Why can't records with piggy-back attributes be saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I recently run into a problem where records were marked as readonly. Checking out the documentation I found this:

"Records loaded through joins with piggy-back attributes  will be marked as read only since they cannot be saved. "

Why not? My model looks like the following:

```
class MailAccount
    belongs_to :account, :class_name => "UserAccount"
    named_scope :active, :joins => :account, 
      :conditions => "user_accounts.archived_at IS NULL"
end
```

I find no reason why models loaded retrieved with this named scope can not be saved. Any ideas?

Comment: The solution belongs in an answer below, with a green checkmark next to it.

Comment: Thank you Ignacio for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out I had to add `:select => "mail_accounts.*"` to the scope, or otherwise the query would store attributes from `user_accounts` in the `MailAccount` object, which prevented it from being saved.

So the proper code to use is:

```
class MailAccount
    belongs_to :account, :class_name => "UserAccount"
    named_scope :active, :joins => :account, 
      :conditions => "user_accounts.archived_at IS NULL",
      :select => "mail_accounts.*"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a :join, the ActiveRecord model for that associated object is not instantiated. You should use :include instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I use it as a pure selection scope and don't normally need the association class otherwise. In those cases I do though, it might be better to use your solution because of efficiency reasons.